# Error reporting tool for SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, error-reporting, tsqlt

I am looking for an open-source web reporting tool for my tSQLt errors on a SQL Server database. When I run unit tests tSQLt generates the below mentioned information on a table. I want to generate and display it on the web page with graphical format.

```
  [TestCase]
  [Name]
  [TranName]
  [Result]
  [Msg]
```

Are there any open-source tools to just plugin the application and display the results in graphical format.

Thanks
Viki

Comment: Sounds like you've got an opportunity to contribute to the open source community ;)

Comment: Are you asking for something open source or something free? SQL Server already includes SSRS for reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer for my question. As per the idea given by Dave, there is a continous integration tool called Cruise Control which was posted in tSQLt site itself.

Here is the link: http://tsqlt.org/177/integrating-tsqlt-with-cruise-control/

We can also integrate with the Cruise Control.NET from ThoughtWorks. There is a good explantion over here: http://www.the-wombat-speaks.co.uk/blog/post/2012/12/06/integrating-sqltest-tsqlt-cruisecontrolnet

It helped me alot which we can continously integrate the build and generate the test results.

-Vikram

Comment: I'm glad you got the inspiration you needed to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything pre-built, however, the tSQLt framework can output results from this table in XML using XmlResultFormatter (I covered how to do this in step 5 of [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/using-sql-test-database-unit-testing-with-teamcity-continuous-integration/) about database CI processes). This output is very close to XUnit format, so I suggest you look at adapting an XSL from nUnit to format it for display in a web page.

Hope that helps,

Dave.